# If I uploadAttachmentWithMetadata why don't I see the attachment in the CRaSH shell using "attachments trustInfo"

Tags: corda

I am learning to work with Attachments and I noticed something I can't explain.  If I upload an attachment in the CRaSH shell using:

```
run uploadAttachment jar: path/to/the/file.zip
```

...it *will* appear in the list of Attachments when I run:

```
attachments trustInfo
```

However if I run:

```
run uploadAttachmentWithMetadata jar: path/to/the/file.zip, uploader: Tywin, filename: file.zip
```

...it will *not* appear in the list of Attachments.

The same behavior occurs if I upload attachments with their metadata through RPC or SSH.

The attachments with their metadata *do* successfully upload to the node because I can search for them using RPC and even download them from the CRaSH shell.  They just won't show up in the attachments trustInfo list.  This may seem minor but when I bump into things like this it makes me wonder if there is some fundamental aspect of Attachments I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trustInfo command only returns trusted attachments.

Attachments are trusted if one of the following is true:

- They are uploaded by a trusted uploader
- There is another attachment in the attachment store, that is trusted and is signed by at least one key that the given attachment is also signed with

Trusted Uploaders are: app, rpc, and TestDSL.

So any user attachment not signed by a key that was used to sign a previous trusted attachment is UNTRUSTED and not fetched.

Comment: this is a good summary but I am still confused why `run uploadAttachment` produces a trusted attachment while `run uploadAttachmentWithMetadata` produces an un-trusted attachment?  Both are run from the CRaSH shell. Does the "uploader" parameter of `uploadAttachmentWithMetadata` overwrite something?

Comment: with uploadAttachmentWithMetadata you explicitly specify the uploader, while with uploadAttachment, the uploader is inferred as rpc.